# Transfer hive query result from one hadoop cluster to another hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, oozie, distcp

I have two clusters A and B. Cluster A has 5 tables. Now I need to run a hive query on these 5 tables, result of the query should update the cluster B Table data(covers all the columns of result query)

Note: We should not create any files on cluster A during this process but temp file is allowed.

Can this doable?  What are permissions/Configurations required between two clusters two achieve this?

How Can I get this task/Any other efficient alternative?

After achieving this task, I should automate using Oozie..

Answer (score 0):

Do you use a database for each cluster's metadata or hive tables? If yes then - if you use the same database for storing hive tables in both clusters then you can share them. I know it sounds intuitive, but just mentioned it incase you haven't thought about it.